# maximized profit w/ a cost & demand function

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble with this problem:

If

$C(x) = 14000 + 500x − 4.8x^2 + 0.004x^3$

is the cost function and

$p(x) = 4100 − 9x$

is the demand function, find the production level that will maximize profit. (Hint: If the profit is maximized, then the marginal revenue equals the marginal cost.)

I think that in order to find the answer, I have to find the derivatives of both the equations and set them equal to each other. However, I am getting multiple roots and none of the roots are the answers. What should I be looking for if not the roots?

Answer (score 4):

Let $P(x)$ be the profit function, then
$$
\begin{align}
P(x)&=x\cdot p(x)-C(x)\\
&=x(4100 − 9x)-(14000 + 500x − 4.8x^2 + 0.004x^3)\\
&=4100x-9x^2-14000 - 500x + 4.8x^2 - 0.004x^3\\
&=-14000+3600x-4.2x^2- 0.004x^3.\\
\end{align}
$$
To maximize the profit function, take its first derivative and set equal to zero.
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dP}{dx}&=0\\
\frac{d}{dx}(-14000+3600x-4.2x^2- 0.004x^3)&=0\\
3600-8.4x-0.012x^2&=0.\tag1
\end{align}
$$
Multiply $(1)$ by $\dfrac{1000}{12}$, yield
$$
\begin{align}
300000-700x-x^2&=0\\
x^2+700x-300000&=0\\
(x-300)(x+1000)&=0.
\end{align}
$$
Since $x\ge 0$, then the possible solution is $x=300$. The maximum profit is $P(300)$.

Answer (score 3):

The revenue is $x\cdot p(x)$.  If you take the derivative of that and set it equal to the derivative of cost, I find a single positive solution.